# Change bootstrap 4 collaplse state with localStorage

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

So I have a localStorage which is true of false, and if it's true the `collaplse` should be shown, and if flase `hidden` on page load. But how can I change the state automatic, if the localStorage is either true/false?

My localStorage is

```js
function showTable(display) {
    if (display) {
        localStorage.setItem("dashboardViewTable", display);
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem("dashboardViewTable", display);
    }
}
```

I tried to see if the class just could be removed/added but that doesn't work?

```js
function getTableState() {
    var element = document.getElementById("dashboardViewTable");
    if (localStorage.getItem("dashboardViewTable")) {
        element.classList.add("show");
    } else {
        element.classList.remove("show");
    }
}
```

How do I change the toggling of a bootstrap collaplse, with js?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#via-javascript